# g{movement} does not work caret in normal mode in vsvim

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsvim

I am having problem with g$ and g0 in vsvim under VS2013.

This happened after i upgraded my package. Is there any settings that i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This somehow resolved after i added a .vsvimrc file.